# Sybase-AseBulkCopy Fails When Changing the EnableBulkLoad In ConnectionString

Tags: sqlbulkcopy, sybase-ase15

I am using C#/ADO.NET/AseBulkCopy to copy several table from SQL Server to Sybase.

When the EnableBulkLoad is set to 0, everything works great, although it takes hours to process.

When the EnableBulkLoad is set to 1 or 2, any table with a DateTime gives the error: 
 **String was not recognized as a valid DateTime**.

Versions:

Sybase 15.7 (Linux Server)
SQL Server 2014
Visual Studio 2015

I could post the code, but it's pretty straightforward. Again, the columns obviously map fine, no problems with Identity columns, Foreign Keys, etc. since it works with the EnableBulkLoad is 0.

Any options I should be setting that I am unaware of?

**UPDATE 9/19/2018**
Found The Error, although I am sure there are more issues than these:

NOTE: these are only when EnableBulkServer = 1 or 2, these don't happen when it's 0

```
1. I eliminated my Default Date in the target Sybase table
2. All tinyint fields were changed to char(1) in the target Sybase table
```

I am sure these are bugs and not by design.

Comment: Found The Error, although I am sure there are more issues than these:
<br/>
NOTE: these are only when EnableBulkServer = 1 or 2, these don't happen when it's 0 <br/>

 1. I eliminated my Default Date in the target Sybase table
 2. All tinyint fields were changed to char(1) in the target Sybase table

I am sure these are bugs and not by design.